# Can't use function return value in write

Tags: php

I got new one problem with empty or trim function. I guess trim cant return a boolean but I dont know why ? :c

```
$author = htmlentities($_POST['author']);
        if(empty(trim($author))) $author="Unknown";
```

Gives me this error:

Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: use a ternary operator instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trim the string variable separately. trim() can not return a boolean value as it returns a string value. If you mean that empty() combined with trim() can't return a boolean value, I think that is weird and should work.
Try this:

```
$author = htmlentities($_POST['author']);

$author = trim($author);
if(empty($author)){ 
    $author = "Unknown";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php

"Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). **Instead, use trim($name) == false.**"

Or save `trim($name)` into another variable and use `empty` there

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

> Note:
>
> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
>   result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.